# How to remove this color or error in android app

Tags: android, android-studio

I create a simple application just like Hello world, `api version 28`. But i see this type of color in `AndroidMainfest.XML`

[image]

Comment: This is not an error, it is a warn. Just hover into the highlighted zone and Android Studio will show you the details.

Comment: Put the mouse cursor on the lines and write the warning to see what need solve

Comment: App is not indexable by Google Search; consider adding at least one Activity with an ACTION-VIEW intent filter. See issue explanation for more details. less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Adds URLs to get your app into the Google index, to get installs and traffic to your app from Google Search.  Issue id: GoogleAppIndexingWarning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the solution. Just add this

action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtDvF.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

It is just a warning. Try to write  after `<application`

> tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"

If it is your first project,  it is not needed to know what is it. But you can read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/)